# Sharing Application Resources in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, nested-resources

From [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613559.aspx), I read:

> If your application uses custom controls and defines resources in a ResourceDictionary (or XAML Resources node), it is recommended that you either define the resources at the Application or Window object level, or define them in the default theme for the custom controls. Defining resources in a custom control's ResourceDictionary imposes a performance impact for every instance of that control.

Ok... now, I have a UserControl that defines the following resources:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Namespace:ImagesConverter x:Key="ImagesConverter" ...
        <Storyboard x:Key="AnimationHide" ...
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

So, because of the fact I'm creating not less than 100 instances of them at runtime, as the MSDN tutorial says, it would be better to move those resources ad MainWindow or App level. Where's the best location to move them to? MainWindow level, App level or resource file? And why?

And then... how can I use them from their new location? Let's say I have this code inside my UserControl:

```
m_AnimationHide = (Storyboard)Resources["AnimationHide"];
```

How should I modify it to reflect those changes? And how should I modify the following UserControl XAML snippet instead?

```
Source="{Binding Source={x:Static Properties:Resources.MyImage}, Converter={StaticResource ImagesConverter}}"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I prefer to use `App.xaml` or seperate `ResourceDictionary` over adding them all to the `Window.Resources`, this eliminates clutter in your `Window` xaml.

This also allows you to easily create `Themes` for you application as you have them all in one place, so you can copy your existing `ResourceDictionary` change brush colors etc, the you can choose what `ResourceDictionary` you want to load and and easily change the entire apperance of your application.

As for accessing the `Resouces` in your `Usercontrol` there is no difference on the xaml side, you will continue to use `{StaticResource resourceKey}` as when you call a `StaticResource` it searches though the `Resource` hierarchy to find the `Resource`.

So if you move you resource from `UserControl.Resources` to `Window.Resources` or `Application.Resources` you don't need to change anything in your xaml code that is accessing though `{StaticResource resourceKey}`.

As for access in code behind you will use `FindResource("resourceKey")` instead of `Resources["resourceKey"]`  as `FindResource` will search the hierarchy for the `Resource` like the `StaticResource` does in xaml.

Example:

```
m_AnimationHide = (Storyboard)FindResource("AnimationHide");
```

If you want to modify any of these Resources in a specific control and they are frozen you can just create a copy for that instance

Example

```
var animation = FindResource("AnimationHide") as Storyboard;

m_AnimationHide = animation.Clone();
m_AnimationHide.Completed += m_AnimationHide_Completed;
```

You can also set `x:Shared="false"` this will return a new instance of the animation each time from the Resources, this will save copy/pasting the same animation througout your application if you have a complex Resource that you need to change values in.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="AnimationHide" x:Shared="false" />
```

Then you will be able to modify the resource locally.

Comment: I did like you said but something is going wrong. I have a piece of code in my UserControl that looks like this: `animation.Completed += handler;`. Whenever I reach that. my application crashes telling me: `DoubleAnimation must have IsFrozen set to false to modify`. Those animations must do something on the UserControl that fired them upon completion. How to fix it?

Comment: That because you cant modify the static resource as its frozen, I have added a workaround to my answer

Comment: Thanks! I tried the first approach (all into App) and it works like a charm. Now I'm trying with the second one (all into MainWindow)... but I'm getting unresolved resource errors whenever I try to reference a MainWindow resource into my custom UserControl. Why?

Comment: Because the is no guarantee that the `UserControl` will be placed in that `Window` and have access to its `Resources`, so instead of `{StaticResource resourceKey}` you would use `{DynamicResource resourceKey}`. as this will resolve at runtime.

Comment: The hierarchy for Resources is: Local object -> Visual Tree up to the Root (the window that hosts the control) -> App Resources. So it should work if you put your control into the main window. If the control is hosted in another window, the resources will not be found.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to expand a bit on the reasoning for moving resources out of the control xaml.

Like you read in the MSDN library, the only technical reason behind moving anything to a higher level is to conserver resources (i.e. memory). Each entry in a ResourceDictionary is created as an object (=instance!) at runtime and takes up memory and the initialization takes a few CPU cycles.

Now the catch with something like the StoryBoard: An object that stores data that is relevant to or even connected to a particular instance of the control - like the instance of the executing animation - has to be created for each instance of the control it should drive. Unless you want all your controls to animate identically and in parallel.

To me it doesn't make much sense to use `Clone` in code as opposed to just put that thing into the xaml in the first place. The xaml approach takes a bit of copy/paste and thus would mean to modify the animation in more than one place (if you even *can* re-use something like that across controls) but it will remove the code requirement and still do the same: create an instance of the `Storyboard` for each instance of the control.

Comment: Well it does make sense to `Clone` or use `x:Shared` (xaml version of clone) because if you have a `Themed` application how would you theme that copy/pasted `Resource` easily in multiple places. using either xaml or code clone you only have to change the Resource in the Themed Dictonaries instead of thoughout the entire application.